# How to get csv file name in amazon s3 bucket using python?

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-s3

I am trying to extract CSV file name in a directory in amazon s3 bucket. But it is not working . Can you please help me how to do this?

example:

```
s3://itx-acm-medaff-dev-sourcefiles/Raw_Layer/PCYC_IMBRUVICA/PCYC_VOC_Data_Load.csv
```

expected result:

```
PCYC_VOC_Data_Load.csv
```

Comment: The filename (or `Key` as it is called in Amazon S3) is actually `Raw_Layer/PCYC_IMBRUVICA/PCYC_VOC_Data_Load.csv`. Objects in Amazon S3 store the full path as their Key. Can you tell us what you will be doing this this name, to see which name you actually need to obtain?

Answer (score 0):

using `ls` command we can get the total file in the s3 bucket directory.

```
file = os.popen('aws s3 ls s3://itx-acm-medaff-dev-sourcefiles/Raw_Layer/PCYC_IMBRUVICA/').read()
print(file)
list_file = list(file.split("\n"))
s = str(list_file[0])
s1 = s.split(' ')
print(s1[-1])
```

output:

```
'PCYC_VOC_Data_Load.csv'
```